# PayPal Payment Methods

Tags: paypal

I hope that someone can shed some light on this.

We have developed with PayPal using Website Payments Standard, Website Payments Pro (DoDirectpayment).

There are several other methods like Advanced Checkout, Express Checkout, Payflow Pro, etc. What does each one do? Is there some place where one can see all of these and the differences between them?

Comment: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides

Answer (score 2):

To give you a quick and brief overview of some of the main differences.

Website Payments Standard - Uses HTML buttons buttons that you generate from your PayPal account, or you can use a 3rd party cart, or build your own.  The buyer is basically redirected to the PayPal payment pages, to enter in their information.  You have some control over the checkout flow but are limited in what you can control.  There is no monthly fee for this services.  The buyer is on the PayPal site when they complete the payment.

Website Payments Pro - There is a monthly fee for this service.  With this service, you have full control over the checkout flow.  The buyer stays on your site when they enter in their billing information.  Instead of using HTML and redirecting the buyer over to PayPal, you will be using API calls to send the data over to PayPal and get a response back.

Express Checkout - This is usually used in conjunction with Pro or by itself.  This allows the buyer to checkout with PayPal instead of using their credit card directly on your site.  The buyer is redirected over to the PayPal site to sign in or to pay with a credit card.  No billing information is entered in on your site.  This method uses API call similar to Pro, and allows for some control over the checkout flow.  You will have more control with this than you would with Website Payments Standard.  The buyer will be back on your site when they actually complete the payment.  There is no monthly charge for this service.

Payflow Pro - This is similar to Website Payments Pro.  There is a monthly service charge for this service.  You can either use the API's and keep the buyer on your site where they enter in all of the information and complete the payment.  Otherwise you could also use the hosted checkout pages and have the buyer enter in their billing information on PayPal's pages allowing you to be PCI compliant.  Also with Payflow, you can use your own processor as long as it is one that is compatible with Payflow.  So don't have to use PayPal as your processor if you choose not to.

Hope this helps.